# Getting error "unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'set'" while printing items in a set in color in putty terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 sets: set1 and set2. I am able to print items of set1 in green color in terminal so that while printing differences in output so that it is easy to recognize that which item is from which set but getting error while printing differences with set1 items in green color.
I am using python 3.4.4

2 sets:

```
set1 = {'Amy', 'Jacob'}
set2 = {'Jacob', 'Serp'}
print(list(set1 ^ set2)) #printing the differences between two sets in below output. Using list because there will may sets and all the differences will be in list

['Amy', 'Serp']
```

I have tried using termcolor and it is able to print items of set1 in green color

```
from termcolor import colored
set1 =colored(set(x[key1]), 'green')
```

but when it is printing the differences using below code

```
set1 =colored(set(x[key1]), 'green')
set2 = {'Jacob', 'Serp'}
print(list(set1 ^ set2))
```

Below error is coming so I am unable to print item of set1 in green color in output which is difference between two sets

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    print((set1 ^ set2))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'set'
```

Expected output is below where Amy should be written in green color.

```
['Amy', 'Serp']
```

Comment: The color has nothing to do with the data being compared, so the coloring shouldn't be applied until after you've done the comparison. As the error notes, `colored` returns a string, not a "colored version" of the initial structure.

Comment: What are `a` and `b` in your code? Are they an alias for `set1` and `set2`?

Comment: updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you color the set like this:

```
from termcolor import colored
set1 = {'Amy', 'Jacob'}
set2 = {'Jacob', 'Serp'}
set12 = colored(set1, 'green')
print(set12)
print(type(set12))
```

Output:
[image]

The set is casted to a string colored as you could see, and you were diferencing a set with a string, so that's why the error.
Another way to do it could be change every element of the set, but this doesn't work, because when you colored a string, you are appending some characters to give that color, as you can see below, so when you do the differnce it will output te two sets concatenated:

```
from termcolor import colored
set1 = {'Amy', 'Jacob'}
set2 = {'Jacob', 'Serp'}
set11 = {colored(i, 'green') for i in set1}
print(set11)
print(type(set11))
print(set11^set2)
```

Output:
[image]

The way that you can try is to get the difference, and if some element of the difference is in `set1`, color it with green, and then join them into a string to color the print:

```
from termcolor import colored
set1 = {'Amy', 'Jacob'}
set2 = {'Jacob', 'Serp'}
print('[', ', '.join({colored(i, 'green') if i in set1 else i for i in set1^set2 }),']')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: thanks. But when I use below code ```('[', ', '.join({colored(i, 'green') if i in set1 else i for i in set1^set2 }),']')``` as a variable to use in some other function then it gives output in this way: 
     ```'Serp, \x1b[32mAmy\x1b[0m' ```

Comment: Glad it helps you, maybe you could [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer :). And, yeah, that's because of the colored, if you want to work with variables like set1^set2, I suggest you to do it without coloring them. I mean you must not color them, only if you want to print them. So you can maybe use a list of colors for the sets or create a function that prints the sets like that... Yeah it's quite innefficient but that's how termcolor works.

Comment: Sure I will do that. I think may be I need to use variable to items of both the sets in difference output instead of green coloring. Expected output on printing ```print(list(set1 ^ set2))``` should be  ```['Amy--Set1', 'Serp--Set2']``` can you help me with this?

Comment: Sure, look, try with: `print([(i+'--'+'Set1') if i in set1 else (i+'--'+'Set2') if i in set2 else '' for i in set1^set2])`